# data exchange between R and python (music21)

Tags: python, r, music21

My goal is to take a text file with a number list generated by R (e.g  1 2 3 4), and "translate" the numbers into music21 notes (that is, to compose a melody when each note is identified with a number).

Having the number list, one idea I had was creating a R vector with strings that matches with music21 note names, and trying to get a new output with the note names instead of numbers. But I'm not very sure of that. Besides, I don't know how to proceed after that.

I also read some topics talking about using R as a subprocess in Python, but again, I couldn't clearly understand how that works (the fact that running the subprocess almost makes my poor old laptop crash had something to do with that...)

How can I proceed here?

Comment: Hi! Do you have some code that you've tried? If so could you post it in the question? It would also be helpful to see examples of what the data looks like and what it should end up looking like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would try to use only python. I realize you have little experience with it; but python is more general purpose than R and should be able to do anything R can do. Trying to use both at the same time seems like it would generate additional complexity and overhead you simply don't need.

It looks this music21 takes notes and lengths; however there are also rests. Let's say you have a list for durations called "durations", and a list for notes (and rests) called notes:

```
from music21 import *

mymusic = stream.Stream()

notes = ["F4", "F4", "rest", "F4"]
durations = [0.25, 1, 0.25, 1]

for n,d in zip(notes, durations):
    if n == "rest":
        mymusic.append(note.Rest(d))
    else:
        mymusic.append(note.Note(n,d))

mymusic.show("midi")
```

Music21 uses a special kind of list called a stream. We're making an empty stream first, and then populating it with notes and durations. Zip lets us walk through both lists at the same time. We chekc if the note is supposed to be a rest; if it is a rest we add the rest with the right duration, else we continue to add a note of the right duration. (notice I am not a composer, you could generate the notes and durations any way you like :-) ).

If you really wanted to; you could write a csv file or something of notes and durations in R and read that in python. However, I think generating the lists in python itself is a cleaner approach.

Thanks for introducing me to this music21 library, it looks very neat.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a better Idea now. I'll try something like that.
Anyway, I'll probably keep working on R and writting .csv or .txt files, it's not just because of confort. Generating the lists I mentioned before uses random tools that will probably require (or work better) on R.

Comment: Have a look at python's random module! It does all sorts of neat things :-)  might be a bit overwhelming at first, you probably just need randint, randrange and/or choice. Let me know if you have issues accessing csv's in python; might be able to help if you're stuck.